# Change button colour on mouse over - XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a button that will be of a particular color (say red). On MouseOver the button color changes to some other color (say black).

Here's what I've tried:

```
<Style x:Key="CategoryButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And I used it as:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCat1" Click="btnCat1_Click" Background="#FFFF1D1D" Style="{StaticResource CategoryButton}">
    Hello ...
</Button>
```

The problem is when I say `Background="#FFFF1D1D"` the trigger color doesn't make any change to the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you've specified `Background` in the Button declaration (in other words a local value) which has precedence over the Style trigger. The property precedence for WPF is described at msdn, [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

A short excerpt from the page with the related properties for this question:

> Highest precedence is listed first
>    3. Local value.
>    6. Style triggers.
>   8. Style setters

The solution is to remove the local value and set it with the Style instead.

```
<Button x:Name="btnCat1"
        Click="btnCat1_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource CategoryButton}">
    Hello ...
</Button>

<Style x:Key="CategoryButton" TargetType="Button">
    <!-- Set background property here -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF1D1D" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can also inherit the style in case you don't wish to set the background for all CategoryButton's

```
<Style x:Key="RedCategoryButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CategoryButton}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF1D1D" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extended example of `WPF` Button styling in `XAML` shown below (place in in Windows `ResourceDictionary` file):

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Button_Command">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#a0a0a0"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="#909090">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Border.BorderThickness>0</Border.BorderThickness>
                    <Border.CornerRadius>2</Border.CornerRadius>
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#e0e0e0" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#808080" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                         <Setter TargetName="ButtonBackground" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f0f0f0" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#c0c0c0" Offset="0.81" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#d50101" Offset="0.81" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f50101" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonBackground" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f0f0f0" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#c0c0c0" Offset="0.75" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#d50101" Offset="0.75" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f50101" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note the different styling pertinent to `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">` and `<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">`

Hope this will help. Regards,